# How can to print the input without storing it in c++?

Tags: python, c++

I want to deal with the input stream without storing it in the memory. Currently, what I'm doing is

```
String mem;
cin >> mem;
cout << mem << endl;
```

But, something like

```
cout << cin;
```

is not possible. I get

```
error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator>>’ (operand types are ‘std::istream {aka std::basic_istream<char>}’ and ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’)
     cin >> cout;
```

In Python 2.7, I can do

```
print input()
```

Is there any way to do this in C/C++ too?

Comment: Even if you don't want it to be stored in the memory - it doesn't matter if you write it as a one-liner - it will be stored in the memory

Comment: have you tried `read`, `getline`, `get` functions of `cin`?

Comment: As @SelçukCihan wrote, everything is stored in memory. And there is nothing wrong with that! What do you actually want to accomplish? I guess you don't want to store it in a named varable? Or are you concerned about memory consumption, because the input is too big? The right answer depends on what you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cout << cin.rdbuf();` will do it.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. But, the program never terminates. I need it for just one input-output pair.

Comment: It terminates as soon as `cin` terminates. Usually with a ctrl-D, sometimes a ctrl-Z.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot. You should store input in variable. C++ is not python and `operator >>` is overloaded for different types. Also, functions like `read`, `readsome` receives buffer, where data should be putted.

Comment: Actually, you can do pretty much the same thing that python does. You can have function `print` and function `input` and then do `print(input());`. The question is, of course, what difference does that make?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using stream iterators:

```
#include <iterator>
//...
std::cout << *std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin) << '\n';
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing i can imagine is somthing like this:

```
template< typename T >
struct In: public T
{
    T& operator << ( istream &in )
    {
        in >> *this; 
        return *this;
    }
};

cout << ( In<string>() << cin );
```

Answer (score 1):

For a single character, you can try `std::cout.put(std::cin.get())`. For a string, I think there are no ways to do it without using a temp variable. Generally speaking, you should always try to do something with the input, so the design of the language is try to ease the way reading input to variables, not directly get your input and put to output.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char a;
cout<<a==cin>>a;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: check if it helps you.

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations, why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...

Comment: @Pravin No, this does not help. You have declared a char.

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << input();
```

Call the function input if you want.

Comment: `input()` is a built-in function in python.

Comment: i thought you wanted solution for c++ . common sense will tell you to use different function name.